# Highchart basic column time sensitive comparison side by side

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have a set of data I want to chart into highcharts:

Series 1:

```
0
: 
{tbldate: "1665545400000", tbldata: 39.960960388183594}
1
: 
{tbldate: "1665547200000", tbldata: 2.3699917793273926}
2
: 
{tbldate: "1665550800000", tbldata: 55.46766662597656}
3
: 
{tbldate: "1665554400000", tbldata: 90.57756042480469}
4
: 
{tbldate: "1665558000000", tbldata: 53.59600067138672}
5
: 
{tbldate: "1665561600000", tbldata: 60.070308685302734}
```

and Series 2:

```
0
: 
{tbldate: "1665631800000", tbldata: 18.298175811767578}
1
: 
{tbldate: "1665633600000", tbldata: 90.40299224853516}
2
: 
{tbldate: "1665637200000", tbldata: 9.714997291564941}
3
: 
{tbldate: "1665640800000", tbldata: 13.358141899108887}
4
: 
{tbldate: "1665644400000", tbldata: 39.14616012573242}
5
: 
{tbldate: "1665648000000", tbldata: 76.88685607910156}
```

Basically, series 1 contains the data with a date today and I want to compare it with series 2 which contains data with a date yesterday.

I can't seem to make the chart compare side by side like the example here https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic because my data is time sensitive.

Ive tried using linkedTo but it doesnt seems to work

Below I include my chart option:

```
chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: "column",
      height: "500px",
      zoomType: "x",
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: "Energy Usage Comparison",
      float: true,
      style: { color: "#333333", fontSize: "12px" },
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime",
      title: {
        text: null,
      },
      tickWidth: 0,
      reversed: false,
      labels: {
        y: 15,
      },
      minPadding: 0,
      maxPadding: 0,
      startOnTick: true,
      endOnTick: true,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      showLastLabel: true,  
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: "",
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormat:
        '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.2f} mm</b></td></tr>',
      footerFormat: "</table>",
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
      },
    },
    series: [{}],
  };
```

And this is how my chartoption.series looks like:

```
      this.chartOptions.series = [
        {
          type: "column",
          name: "Current",
          color: "#72A2C0",
          data: tempCurrent[0].data,
          columnOffset: 0,
        },
        {
          linkedTo: ":previous",
          type: "column",
          name: "Previous",
          color: "#192E5B",
          data: tempPrevious[0].data,
          columnOffset: 1,
        },
      ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to preprocess your data to adapt `x` values and show the correct value in a tooltip. For example:

```
const data1 = [{
  tbldate: "1665545400000",
  tbldata: 39.960960388183594
}, ...];

const data2 = [{
  tbldate: "1665631800000",
  tbldata: 18.298175811767578
}, ...];

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: "column"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: data1.map(dataEl => [+dataEl.tbldate, dataEl.tbldata])
  }, {
    data: data2.map(dataEl => [dataEl.tbldate - oneDay, dataEl.tbldata])
  }],
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function(tooltip) {
      const series = this.series;
      const date = this.x;
      const point = tooltip.bodyFormatter([this]);
      const header = tooltip.tooltipFooterHeaderFormatter(
        series.index === 1 ? {
          ...this,
          key: this.key + oneDay
        } :
        this
      );

      return header + point;
    }
  },
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e37b518u/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter